# How to store call logs from android device on localhost database?

Tags: android, database, localhost, calllog

I am working on an android app and I want to store call logs in database. Can someone please tell me is it possible and how to do it programmatically? Thanks

Here is my code for accessing call logs from the device

call logs.java

```
public class Call_log extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_log);

        Cursor mCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, null);
        int number = mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int date = mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        int type = mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phnumber = mCursor.getString(number);
            String callduration = mCursor.getString(duration);
            String calltype = mCursor.getString(type);
            String calldate = mCursor.getString(date);
            Date d = new Date(Long.valueOf(calldate));
            String callTypeStr = "";
            switch (Integer.parseInt(calltype)) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    callTypeStr = "Outgoing";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    callTypeStr = "Incoming";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    callTypeStr = "Missed";
                    break;
            }
            sb.append("Phone number " + phnumber);
            sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            sb.append("Call duration " + callduration);
            sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            sb.append("Call type " + callTypeStr);
            sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            sb.append("Call date " + d);
            sb.append("---------------------------");
            sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }

        TextView callDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.call_logs);
        callDetails.setText(sb.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: any problem with your code?

Comment: No there is no problem with my code..it works fine. I wanted to know if I can store my call logs on database so that I can access it later from another device.